# MySQL: Show daily count of created rows with inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a users and user_data table. I'm trying to show signups by `created_at` and group it by the count for that day, and show a record for each day, so I can see the increment of user sign ups.

user_data is optional, and isn't always there (yet), but I only want to count rows which do have a user_data row.

I'm running this, but its just returning 1 row for each user sign up, how can I group the dates?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), created_at, email 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_data  ON users.id = user_data.user_id
GROUP BY users.created_at, email
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems that you want to show a count of user signups by date and group them accordingly. For better understand your requirements and provide more accurate guidancelike giving sample tables and expected results.

Here is the modified query :

```
SELECT DATE(u.created_at) AS signup_date, COUNT(*) AS signups
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_data ud ON u.id = ud.user_id
GROUP BY signup_date
ORDER BY signup_date ASC;SELECT DATE(u.created_at) AS signup_date, COUNT(*) AS signups
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_data ud ON u.id = ud.user_id
GROUP BY signup_date
ORDER BY signup_date ASC;
```

THis will give you date wise count of signups.